# Where in Visual Studio I can edit code template for property refactoring?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, prism

I have VS 2012 with ReSharper, I also use PRISM. Not sure where it comes from, but I get following choices when placing mouse pointer on a property

[image]

I want to edit template used for those, specifically last one (with `RaisePropertyChanged(Expression..`)

This 3rd option looks prism-specific, but I wonder where it's hooked up? I checked all settings in Visual Studio but can't find it.

Comment: did you check in `My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Snippets\1033` ?

Comment: For some reason my VS is under Visual Studio 11.0.. No, I didn't find it there..

Comment: Unless someone knows an answer I'd simply search the entire PC for *.snippet files and see what comes out. If nothing, probable conclusion is it's coded into a plugin/extension (if that is even possible)

Answer (score 0):

It is ReSharper Alt+Enter menu, not Visual Studio one, so Visual Studio does not have an option to adjust it.
These context actions are INotifyPropertyChanged support in ReSharper ([more info](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/24/inotifypropertychanged-support-in-resharper-7/)). Unfortunately, there is no way to edit templates of ReSharper context actions.